# How can I search for different types of items on my phone?

Tags: search

I recently got a Samsung i5800. I was hoping that the search widget would search everything on my phone - contacts calendar, memo - but it seems all it does it to search contacts.

Can anyone recommend a better search app that will do what I've listed above? To be specific, I'm looking for an app such that if I have a memo, calendar entry, or contact with the word **Jugular** and I type **Jugular** in the edit field of the app, it will display the memo, calendar entry and contact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: App recommendations are off-topic here, you may want to edit your post before a mod closes your question.

Answer (score 5):

Go to SETTINGS > SEARCH > SEARCHABLE ITEMS

Then tick mark all the things you want to be able to search for from the Search Box. Applications like Evernote, Dropbox, Catch, Meridian, ColorDict and many others which are compatible and you have installed should be listed. You can pick and choose whichever options suit you.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I saw this option on my phone, but I didn't see Calendar or Memo listed. Maybe I should get a memo/calendar app that do allow searching?

Comment: I don't think the calendar is searchable because its the TouchWiz calendar. Samsung did not add the searchable functionality to their calendar, or Memo.

Comment: A syncable note taking app like Catch has support for search - try that.

Answer (score 4):

The "[Google Search Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&feature=search_result)", which is different then the "Search Widget" will search contacts, apps, web and I think other things if the app "plugs in" to the search framework. I am not sure if it does calendar events though. But according to the screenshot in the market, it will.

Comment: Thanks, but reading the reviews, I'm not too encouraged to get this...